# How can I find the age (year of manufacture) of a pc running Ubuntu

Tags: hardware

How can I find the manufacture date of my PC?  i.e. any of the key components like HD or CPU.

`lshw`, `smartctl`, `lspci` will tell me what I have installed but not how old it is.

Comment: Try `dmidecode` It could give you some clues

Comment: no dates in the output,  I can post it if you like, what were you thinking would be visible?

Comment: It depends on the computer I suppose. On mine I got a bios date

Comment: The OEM Strings section might contain the date you're looking for: $ sudo dmidecode | grep -i -B1 -A8 "oem strings"

Comment: Building on Jean-Marie's excellent advice above, something like this _may_ work for many cases: `sudo dmidecode | egrep '199[0-9]|20[0-3][0-9]'` For host of reasons it's imprecise, will miss years that omit the century, and may reflect dates other than the manufacture date. But for crude estimation, possibly good enough!

Comment: When you have identified the CPU, you can check via the manufacturer's website. For example Intel: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors

Comment: @AlanDeSmet it worked but I don't know if the date is MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY